# Only get the attribute from element, where Event was fired in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

iam new to AngularJS. I try to move from Backbone.js to Angular and first think i want to do its quite simple: fadeIn and fadeOut.

So my HTML look like these:

```
<div id="calendar" style="padding-left: 50px" ng-controller="CalendarButtonController">
    <!-- prev button -->
    <div class="calendar-btn prev" ng-mouseover="fadeIn()" ng-mouseleave="fadeOut()" fade-duration="5000" fade-target="btnPrev">
        <img id="btnPrev" src="img/btn-prev_hover.png"> 
    </div>

    <!-- next button -->
    <div class="calendar-btn next" ng-mouseover="fadeIn()" ng-mouseleave="fadeOut()" fade-duration="5000" fade-target="btnNext">
        <img id="btnNext" src="img/btn-next_hover.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

So the idea is: If the mouse is over prev-button div, the image inside the div will be fade in. In the fade-target-Attribute is the specific ID of the element, which will be faded. On mouseover the element (defined in the fade-target-Attribute) will be fade in and on mouseleave the element will be fade out. So i implemented a controller and a directive:

```
function CalendarButtonController($scope){
    $scope.fadeIn = function() {
        $scope.$emit('event', 'fadeIn');
    }

    $scope.fadeOut = function() {
        $scope.$emit('event', 'fadeOut');
    }
}

angular.module('components', [])
    .directive('fadeDuration', function ($rootScope) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, el, attrs) {              
                $rootScope.$on('event', function(event, message) {
                    if(message  == "fadeIn"){
                        fadeIn();
                    }

                    if(message  == "fadeOut"){
                        fadeOut();
                    }
                });

                function fadeIn(){
                    $('#'+attrs.fadeTarget).fadeIn(attrs.fadeDuration);             
                }

                function fadeOut(){
                    $('#'+attrs.fadeTarget).fadeOut(attrs.fadeDuration);                
                }
            }
        }       
    });
```

The fadein and fadeout of the element works, but the problem is: If i move the mouse over the prev-button-div both images (prev-Button and next-Button) fade in. But it should only fade in the image of prev-Button. How is it possible, to get only the attribute of an element, where the event was fired? In the directive are alway all attributes from all elements matching the directive.

Edit: And is there a easier way to achieve a fadeIn and fadeOut effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to control the DOM events through the scope or controller, move that event binding logic to the directive, and then use normal jquery there. You shouldn't need to communicate with the directives using scope events most of the times.

Easier showing than explaining (checkout [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WRms8/8/))

```
<div ng-controller="itemsController">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <div class="item" fade="mouseover" fade-duration="5000" fade-target="item-{{item.name}}">
            <span id="item-{{item.name}}">{{item.name}}</span>
        </div>        
    </div>    
</div>

myApp.controller('itemsController', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{ name: 'Foo' }, { name: 'Bar'}, { name: 'Baz'}];    
});

myApp.directive('fade', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            var fadeDuration = attrs.fadeDuration || 100;
            var onEvent = attrs.fade || "mouseover";

            // See how the directive alone controls the events, not the scope
            element.on(onEvent, function() {
                var targetElement = $('#' + attrs.fadeTarget);
                targetElement.fadeOut(fadeDuration, function(){
                   targetElement.fadeIn(fadeDuration);                   
                });                
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Also, note how the 'element' parameter is already a jquery wrapped dom element, so no need for doing $('#something') again

Comment: Thanks for your help. The element, which will be faded, is not the same element, which fire the event. As you can see in HTML code example, the event should be fired if the mouse is over the div. And the chield element of the div (img) should be fade in. So i cant use element of the link funcion, i need a reference to the element witch is defined in the fade-target-Attribute.

Comment: Oops, didn't catch that at the first reading. Just updated the fiddle to consider a different fade target, like you described.

Comment: Although, for this case, I'd probably prefer using something like element.children().first() rather than a fade-target attribute - but since I don't know if you plan to use this for something else, I changed the fiddle anyway.

Comment: I love Angular for data-binding and its Ajax handling, but for pure (non-DOM changing) effects like this why use Angular directives instead of straight jQuery ? It'd be half as long and seemingly more maintainable. Is there a reason I'm missing ?

Comment: At this particular case, one advantage is, in the process, you created a reusable instruction for fading elements. Also, if you ever need to make this work together with scope changes, you could do it too (imagine, for example, the fade-target could be a string defined at your scope/controller). 
The coolest reason IMO for directives is making it easier to use the plugins, once the directive is created, with simple declarative html instructions. Checkout these directives for Bootstrap, for example: http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/